# issue with hangman/ word guessing game

Tags: vb.net

I am making a hangman game. when i press a button i need to put in a word which then becomes the word that i need to guess. i got a problem with how to check the word for a letter that i put into a inputbox when i press a button. if the letter is in the word the letter i gave needs to change from * to the letter it self. for example word:house that needs to be converted to password characters and the guessed letter: o   then it should become *o*** . when there are multiple letters in the word they all need to be shown.

this is my code its in dutch but i hope u can help 
here is the translation of some the words: woord,word ster,star aantalletters,amountofletters nieuwwoord,newword Geef het woord,give the word geef een geldig woord in, give a valid word  jammer mis, to bad wrong letter

code:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim woord, tip, ster As String
Dim aantalletters As Integer 
Dim letter As String
Dim nieuwwoord As String

Private Sub btnnieuwspel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnnieuwspel.Click
    txtwoord.Text = ""
    Try
      woord = InputBox("Geef het woord.", "Het woord")
      Do While woord = "" Or woord < 0 Or woord > 0
        If woord = "" Or woord < 0 Or woord > 0 Then
          MessageBox.Show("geef een geldig woord in")
        End If
        woord = InputBox("Geef het woord.", "Het woord")
      Loop
    Catch
    End Try
    Try
      tip = InputBox("Geef de tip", "De tip")
    Catch

    End Try

    aantalletters = woord.Length
    lblTip.Text = "Tip:" & tip

    For i = 1 To aantalletters
      txtwoord.Text = txtwoord.Text & "*"
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub btnSluiten_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSluiten.Click
  Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnletter_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnletter.Click
  letter = InputBox("Geef een letter", "De Letter")

  If woord.Contains(letter) Then

  Else
    MessageBox.Show("jammer mis")
  End If        
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to do this, one is as follows:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Dim MyWord      As String
Dim txtwoord    As String

' Just used for testing the loop.
Sub Test_It()
    MyWord = "house"      ' Set test word
    txtwoord = "*****"    ' Set test Mask
    ' Call function with my 'guess'
    Debug.Print "Result: " & Find_Characters("o")
    Debug.Print "Result: " & Find_Characters("e")
    Debug.Print "Result: " & Find_Characters("s")
    Debug.Print "Result: " & Find_Characters("u")
    Debug.Print "Result: " & Find_Characters("h")
End Sub

Function Find_Characters(letter As String) As String
Dim i       As Integer
    For i = 1 To Len(MyWord)    ' Loop thru all characters
        If Mid(MyWord, i, 1) = letter Then    ' If found, replace asterisk
           Mid(txtwoord, i, 1) = letter
        End If
    Next i
    Find_Characters = MyWord & vbTab & txtwoord
    ' Need to stop somehow...
    if InStr(1,txtword, "*") = 0 then Msgbox "Finished guessing... Add code...'
End Function
```